# Password protect all directories and sub directories, but not files

Tags: nginx, regex, directoryindex

As the titles suggests, I am trying to password protect all directories and sub-directories, but not the files.  This is so that I can still browse through the files, and share the download links privately.

I have tried many configurations, but I can't seem to get it to work, here is the latest of many:

```
location ~ ^/(files|files/).*$  {
  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/.htpasswd;
  autoindex on;
}

location ~ ^/files/* {
  autoindex off;
}
```

It is based off [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/574348/how-can-i-password-protect-a-directory-with-nginx-but-not-the-files-within-the).

Thank you in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by doing this:

```
location ~ /files/.*/$  {
  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/.htpasswd;
  autoindex on;
}
```

I'm not sure why, or how it works.  Next step might be to password protect the files with a username and password I can give out to people.